# Tmux won't read ~/.tmux.conf

Tags: tmux

I'm running a tmux session over at another machine through SSH. My `~/.tmux.conf` looks as follows:

```
# set Ctrl-a as the default prefix key combination
# and unbind C-b to free it up
set prefix C-a
unbind-key C-b
```

Nothing fancy as you can see. I've made sure no remaining `tmux` sessions are running by using `killall tmux` as well as `tmux kill-server`. When starting up a new tmux session the prefix seems to be `C-b`, so my best guess is that my conf is not loaded. When using `C-b` + `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf` my prefix changes to `C-a`. Installed tmux through Yum, can't update it any higher with yum.

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 1.6
```

What is going on?

Comment: Not a programming question. Please request migration to superuser.com.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry about that. Flagged it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you have to make sure the `.tmux.conf` is located on your remote machine `$HOME`, not your local `$HOME`.

In the file, you can try this (explanation in comment):

```
unbind C-b  
set -g prefix C-a # change prefix key to Ctrl-a as global opt, same as gnu screen
bind a send-prefix #send ^A, so that you can press ctrl-a a to send ctrl-a
```

BTW, you can compile and install new tmux to your local user without root permission.

Comment: Woah! That did the trick, changing my config to the above fixed my issues! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

because you forget bind send-prefix at the end of configuration. Add the following line and it will work out :)

```
bind-key C-a send-prefix
```